# Android telnet client through apache commons

Tags: java, android, telnet

I am fairly new to Android, i want to write a telnet client app for my Android. I have written the code using Apache commons library for telnet. Now i am able to connect to telnet server (for that i have used Asyctask concept) and able to read login banner after a long time i don't know what is causing that. I have modified the example given in Apache commons to work with my android code.I have two java codes in my "src" folder (MainActivity.java and TelnetClientExample.java). First, i want to get the login prompt and then i want user to interact with it please help, Thanks in advance :)
I am posting my screen capture of what i am getting.

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.telnetapp;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public static int port_int_address;
    private EditText server,port;
    private Button connect;
    public static String ip,port_address;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public static TextView textResponse;
    static String response;
    public InputStream instr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        server = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        port = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
        connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        textResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ip = server.getText().toString();
                port_address = port.getText().toString();
                port_int_address = Integer.parseInt(port_address);
                try{
                    MyClientTask task = new MyClientTask(ip, port_int_address);
                    task.execute();
                }
                catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
              }
         });
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
          String dstAddress;
          int dstPort;
          TelnetClientExample job;
          MyClientTask(String inetAddress, int port){
           dstAddress = inetAddress;
           dstPort = port;
          }
          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
           try {
               job = new TelnetClientExample();
               job.backgroundjob();
            }
           catch (Exception e)
            {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
               try {
                 instr = TelnetClientExample.tc.getInputStream();
                 byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                 int ret_read = 0;
                 do
                 {
                  ret_read = instr.read(buff);
                  if(ret_read > 0)
                   {
                      MainActivity.response += new String(buff, 0, ret_read);
                   }
                 }
                 while (ret_read >= 0);
                }
                 catch (Exception e) {
                    MainActivity.response += e.toString();
                    MainActivity.response += "From reading from telnet server ! \n";
                  }
                textResponse.setText(response);
                super.onPostExecute(result);
             }

    }
}
```

### TelnetClientExample.java

```
package com.example.telnetapp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;
public class TelnetClientExample {
    public String remoteip = MainActivity.ip;
    public int remoteport= MainActivity.port_int_address;
    public static TelnetClient tc = null;
    public  void backgroundjob() throws IOException {

        tc = new TelnetClient();
            try {
                tc.connect(remoteip, remoteport);
                }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
    }

    public void close_con(){
        try {
            tc.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            MainActivity.response += e.toString();
            MainActivity.response += "From reading from disconnecting telnet server ! \n";
        }
    }
}




The problem is in this code snippet . please look into this and help me to get an interactive session.



    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       try {
         instr = TelnetClientExample.tc.getInputStream();
         byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
         int ret_read = 0;
         do
         {
          ret_read = instr.read(buff);
          if(ret_read > 0)
           {
              MainActivity.response += new String(buff, 0, ret_read);
           }
         }
         while (ret_read >= 0);
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
            MainActivity.response += e.toString();
            MainActivity.response += "From reading from telnet server ! \n";
          }
        textResponse.setText(response);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
     }
```

The problem i am getting - [image]

Comment: What errors and exceptions are you encountering? Can you please update your question with that information?

Comment: i have attached a screen capture below my question http://i.stack.imgur.com/LnHX6.png

Comment: Check this link out http://letrungthang.blogspot.in/2011/12/telnet-in-java.html

Comment: I am now able to connect and read data from telnet server but the problem is i am getting the login banner after the session is expired. I am posting my input reading code . please help me so that i can get an interactive session. please look into the code snippet i am posting and i am also posting a screen capture .